# react-native-config change .env file path from root to other folder

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-config

I use from react-native-config in my project and my .env file exist in a sub folder rather than root path.
In build.gradle file i have:

```
project.env.get("APP_VERSION_CODE").toInteger()
```

but when i run the app:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object
```

When i copy .env file to root path it work correct.How can i change default .env file path from root to other sub folder??

Answer (score 0):

Try moving .env file to root folder and also check whether file have "APP_VERSION_CODE" defined. To use env file in other folder you need to add plugin manually in android and ios to access the env file.

Comment: how is this working without any plugin: https://github.com/MCROEngineering/react-native-multitenant-boilerplate